# Is it possible to batch erc20/erc721 approval transactions?

Tags: solidity, transactions

Right now I have to call the approval function on every single token. Is there a way I can do this in fewer transactions?

Comment: Assuming that you're using openzeppeling contracts; it depends on who is the owner of the token; only the token owner can approve an address as operator of the token

Comment: for EOA(Externally Owned Account) it is not possible, because you cannot batch transactions. I think a workaround is to use a multi-sig wallet with 1 signer (EOA) and this wallet will be the owner of the tokens

Answer (score 0):

You can submit multiple transactions at once using Gnosis' multisend lib: https://github.com/gnosis/ethers-multisend

You can find some higher level explanations here: https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4680071-transaction-builder

Comment: Multisend requires on delegateCall. You cannot use delegateCall when approving erc20 and erc721 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution for this we've made a quick front-end called BlockBucket which is a simple [Token MultiSender](https://blockbucket.io/) which batches your transactions from a CSV upload.

Created a bit of a walkthrough video on how to use it here:
https://youtu.be/OFOnIUXMbWE